# What is the minimum required depth of reductions for NP-hardness of SAT?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, np-hardness, circuit-complexity, reductions

As everyone knows, 
SAT is complete for $\mathsf{NP}$ w.r.t. polynomial-time many-one reductions. 
It is still complete w.r.t. $\mathsf{AC^0}$ many-one reductions.

My questions is what is the minimum required depth for the reductions? 
More formally,

> What is the least $d$ such that 
>   SAT is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard w.r.t $\mathsf{AC^0_d}$ many-one reductions?

It seems to me that $\mathsf{AC^0_2}$ should be sufficient? Does anyone know a reference?

Comment: From a quick look, it seems like your question should be answered by "Manindra Agrawal, Eric Allender, Steven Rudich, Reductions in Circuit Complexity: An Isomorphism Theorem and a Gap Theorem, JCSS 57: 127-143, 1999." They say "we prove that all sets complete for NP under AC0 reductions are complete
under reductions that are computable via depth two AC0 circuits." But I may be missing something.

Comment: @Robin, thanks, I will check [Reductions in Circuit Complexity: An Isomorphism Theorem and a Gap Theorem](http://ftp.cs.rutgers.edu/pub/allender/switch3.pdf).

Comment: @Robin, I think it answers my question positively: 

"*Theorem 10. (Gap Theorem) Let C be any proper complexity class. The sets hard for C under non-uniform AC0 reductions are hard for C under non-uniform NC0 reductions.*" and

"*Corollary 4. For every proper complexity class C, every set complete for C under NC0 reductions is complete under reductions computable by depth two AC0 circuits and invertible by depth three AC0 circuits.*"  where *proper* means "*closed under DLogTime-uniform NC1 reductions*".

Would you like to post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Ok, I'll repost it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reposting my comment:

From a quick look, it seems like your question should be answered by "Manindra Agrawal, Eric Allender, Steven Rudich, [Reductions in Circuit Complexity: An Isomorphism Theorem and a Gap Theorem](http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/manindra/isomorphism/non-uniform-ac0-iso.pdf), JCSS 57: 127-143, 1999." They say "we prove that all sets complete for NP under AC0 reductions are complete under reductions that are computable via depth two AC0 circuits." But I may be missing something.